# Link in a fieldset

Tags: fieldsets

I have one fieldset on Sobject which is contain 8 field's set but i need to put LINK on only one field. Is it possible? If so, please tell me the way to achieve that.

Comment: Ohh yes !! you are right. this question is seems like "Adding a Link to a Field in a Field Set ?". but that is not solved my problem.

Comment: If it did not solve your problem, what is different about your scenario ? It may help if you edit the question to provide more details and differentiate from the other question. Else this will get closed as a duplicate..

Comment: you can close as a duplicate. if the answer is getting very soon then it will more helpful to me. about that original one.  Thank you.